# Pathlib list splitting by character instead of full path

Tags: python, list, pathlib

I've written a script that accepts a .txt containing a filename manifest from the user, generates a list using pathlib of files in a directory on the user's computer, compares the lists, and spits out another list of files not found from the user's text file. It seems to work fine, but when I reverse the operation to generate a list of files found by pathlib that are *not* in the user's manifest, I'm hitting a snag. My code looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

fileList = open("fileList.txt", "r")
data = fileList.read()
fileList_reformatted = data.replace('\n', '').split(",")
print(fileList_reformatted)

p = Path('C:/Users/Common/Downloads/compare/').rglob('*')
filePaths = [x for x in p if x.is_file()]
filePaths_string = str(filePaths)
filePaths_reformatted = filePaths_string.replace('WindowsPath(','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('\n','')
filePaths_reformatted.split(",")
print(filePaths_reformatted)

differences1 = []
for element in fileList_reformatted:
    if element not in filePaths_reformatted:
        differences1.append(element)

print("The following files from the manifest were not found:",differences1)

differences2 = []
for element in filePaths_reformatted:
    if element not in fileList_reformatted:
        differences2.append(element)

print("The following unexpected files were found:",differences2)
```

The final operation produces a list of each character in the path one at a time, instead of the full filepath. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks so much.

Comment: first don't do `filePaths_string = str(filePaths)` then all the hacks, just do `filePaths_string = [str(x) for x in filePaths]` you'll get the list of strings directly, without all the list repr stuff

Comment: the use `set` to compute differences easily

Comment: `filePaths_reformatted.split(",")` doesn't do anything. It splits the string, but doesn't store the list anywhere. `filePaths_reformatted` is still a string, so `for element in filePaths_reformatted:` loops over the characters in the string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre or just use the `pathlib.Path` objects! There's no good reason to convert them to strings. Indeed, the whole point is to avoid working with just strings!

Comment: "The final operation produces a list of each character in the path one at a time, instead of the full filepath. What am I doing wrong here? " follow my advice about converting (and full explanation of why your bad method doesn't work is made by Barmar). And you're nearly there. Since your split operation doesn't work, you're left with a string, and you iterate on it (so character by character)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre As a newcomer to pathlib, this is so helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre's solution worked. Is there a way to extend this to check if a file could be in the wrong folder, based upon whether the name before an underscore matches the parent? I tried `if element.Path.name.split("_")[0:1] != element.Path.parent.split("_")[0:1]`, which runs but doesn't seem to find anything.